# Change Color of a selected item in an array

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Suppose I am mapping in array which looks like this **(I am using React)**

```
 <div className="contact-display">                                    
          { this.contactList.length > 0 ? this.contactList.map(x => {
            return (
                <div className="contactlist-individual"> 
                   <img src={x["image"]}  width="40" height="40" /> 
                      <div className="contact-list-text">
                         <p className="contact-list-para-name">  {x["firstName"]} {x["lastName"]}</p>
                          <p className="contact-list-para-number"> {x["number"]} </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                   )}) : null
               }
 </div>
```

Here, my div with `className: contactlist-individual` have following css styles

```
.contactlist-individual {
    padding-left: 2%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

(and I change the  `background-color: #EEEEEE;` on hover), Now, when I select/click any time on of the element mapped through **array.map**, I want to change it's color from **white** to say **green** and thereafter when someone clicks on another element in that mapped array, I went to set the previous selected element back to normal and change the new selected mapped element color to green

**Question:** Can someone please help me in figuring out how i can achieve this?

**Update:** Immediately off my head, I can think of s, assigning unique ID  dynamically (using index from map) and then using onClick event to trigger the function which selects that mapped element using `getElementById` from Vanila JS and then Changing this color.

Can someone suggest a better alternate?

Comment: Have you tried to remove the class `contactlist-individual` from all elements and then add the class to a single element?

Comment: Adding class to single element?

Comment: When you click on an element, remove the `className contactlist-individual` from every element. Then get the reference to the clicked element and add the  `className contactlist-individual` to that element.

Comment: @OrthoHomeDefense Can you please show it in answer with an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way around it is to have a click handler for each item in the list and set the active state for the element on click.

It is not a good idea to have a mix of updating the DOM using javascript directly.

```
toggleState = id => {
    let updatedList = this.state.contactList.map(x => {
      if (x.id === id) {
        x.active = true;
      } else {
        x.active = false;
      }

      return x;
    });

    this.setState({
      contactList: updatedList
    });
  };
```

Example - https://codesandbox.io/s/n9x5wyp0m0

Comment: Trying it out. :)